# What are the numbers in boxes on an A320 ND when terrain is shown?

Tags: navigation, airbus

When the TERR On ND button is pressed on the Airbus A320 Cockpit, the TERR information apears on the ND, and 2 boxes in yellow appear.

[image: A320 "TERR ON ND" button]

[image: A320 ND showing terrain with green numbers in yellow boxes]

What do the numbers 146 and 073 mean respectively?

Answer (score 19):

14600 ft and 7300 ft.

**A320 FCOM DSC-31-45** :

> Minimum and maximum elevations encountered ahead of the aircraft, within the selected ND range.